# How to ask user for number of items and then assign each item a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, syntax, user-input

I couldn't find anything online, so I was wondering if someone could help.  I have the following code:

```
x = str(input("Enter number of unique customers then press enter: "))
```

I want it to then ask the user for a specific number for however many customers the user inputs.  For example say the user inputs "2".  I want to ask: Number for customer 1?  Number for customer 2?

I can't find a way to look at the variable x and use the answer to that to know how many to ask.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need loops:

```
num = int(input('How many customers there are?')
list_customer = []
for i in range(num):
    a = input('number for customer x')
    list_customer.append(a)

print(list_customer[0]) # Number for customer 1
print(list_customer[1]) # Number for customer 2
```

Comment: Of course later you would write that as a list comprehension: `customers = [input(f'number for customer {i + 1}') for i in range(num)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your trying to do. It takes the number of customers entered. Makes a list, then iterates through that list to get the input for that customer number. and will dump that into a `results` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

results = pd.DataFrame()

x = str(input("Enter number of unique customers then press enter: "))

list_of_cust = list(range(0, int(x)))

for i in list_of_cust:
    x2 = str(input("Enter number for customer %d: " %(i+1)))

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[str(i+1), x2]], columns=['cust_no','value'])
    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop = True)
```